# C - ntohl replacing digits with zero's

Tags: c, endianness

In the following program on Little and Big Endians:

```
char *s = "1234";
printf("%08X\n",*(int *)s); //big endian
int little = ntohl(*s);
printf("%08X\n",little);//Little endian
```

I get the following output:

```
34333231
31000000
```

The second line should be the reverse order of the first line. What am I doing wrong?
I have little experience in C, but some experience in other languages.

Comment: You are confusing a string of ASCII characters with an integer representation

Comment: the ASCII value of 1 is 0x31, that't why you see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
int little = ntohl(*((uint32_t*)s));
```

otherwise you're only passing a `char` to `ntohl`, which is why your value is being truncated.

Comment: This is incorrect - A string is a string, an int is an int

Comment: @EdHeal: I believe the OP is deliberately abusing the types for learning purposes.  He knows about the difference between characters and integers, and is using the string as a simple way to see the bytes being reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing strings and integers

```
uint32_t i = 12345;
printf("%08X\n", i);    /* 00003039 */
i = ntohl(i);
printf("%08X\n", i);    /* either 00003039 or 39300000 */
```

Depending on the endianness of your platform, you either get the same output or a bytewise reversed one.